Syslog doesn't accept syslog messages from application which use syslog4j logback appender
I try to create example.
My java application will use syslog logback appender to write to syslog.
I want to up syslog server on my local machine and receive message from application there.
1. Let' start from application side:
logback.xml:
...
<appender name="SYSLOG_APPENDER" class="com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%-5level %logger{35}: %m%n%xEx</pattern>
    </layout>

    <syslogConfig class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig">
        <!-- remote system to log to -->
        <host>localhost</host>
        <!-- remote port to log to -->
        <port>601</port>
        <!-- program name to log as -->
        <ident>java-app</ident>
        <facility>local7</facility>
        <!-- max log message length in bytes -->
        <maxMessageLength>128000</maxMessageLength>
    </syslogConfig>
</appender>

<logger name="syslog" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>
   ...

In application I have following code:
private static final Logger loggerSyslog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("syslog");
...


         loggerSyslog.info("test message");

2. Docker compose
version: '3.6'
services:
  syslog:
    image: balabit/syslog-ng:latest
    container_name: syslog
    entrypoint: /usr/sbin/syslog-ng
    command: "-F -edv"
    ports:
      - 514:514
      - 601:601

and execute docker compose up -d
3. Testing:
I run the application and make sure that this line is executed:
loggerSyslog.info("test message");

Based on github readme:

Syslog-ng will listen on these ports and forwards the logs into the
file /var/log/syslog.

I tried to find this file inside docker container but there are no file with such name.
What could be wrong ? Could you please provide diagnostic steps to find the root cause and then fix it ?
P.S.
I also checked
/var/log/messages

because of this line.
https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/blob/master/docker/syslog-ng.conf#L34C8-L34C26
It contains some content but it is not changing after I execute line
loggerSyslog.info("test message");

So looks like it doesn't write log there
P.P.S
I check content of file etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf inside of my container
#############################################################################
# Default syslog-ng.conf file which collects all local logs into a
# single file called /var/log/messages tailored to container usage.
#
# The changes from the stock, default syslog-ng.conf file is that we've
# dropped the system() source that is not needed and that we enabled network
# connections using default-network-drivers(). Customize as needed and
# override using the -v option to docker, such as:
#
#  docker run ...  -v "$PWD/syslog-ng.conf":/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
#

@version: 4.7
@include "scl.conf"

source s_local {
    internal();
};

source s_network {
    default-network-drivers(
        # NOTE: TLS support
        #
        # the default-network-drivers() source driver opens the TLS
        # enabled ports as well, however without an actual key/cert
        # pair they will not operate and syslog-ng would display a
        # warning at startup.
        #
        #tls(key-file("/path/to/ssl-private-key") cert-file("/path/to/ssl-cert"))
    );
};

destination d_local {
    file("/var/log/messages");
    file("/var/log/messages-kv.log" template("$ISODATE $HOST $(format-welf --scope all-nv-pairs)\n") frac-digits(3));
};

log {
    source(s_local);
    source(s_network);
    destination(d_local);
};

P.P.P.S
I also tried to use another library to send syslog message from java app side:
  TcpSyslogMessageSender messageSender = new TcpSyslogMessageSender();
    messageSender.setDefaultMessageHostname("myhostname"); // some syslog cloud services may use this field to transmit a secret key
    messageSender.setDefaultAppName("my_app"); // +
    messageSender.setDefaultFacility(Facility.LOCAL7); // +
    messageSender.setDefaultSeverity(Severity.INFORMATIONAL);
    messageSender.setSyslogServerHostname("localhost");
    messageSender.setSyslogServerPort(601);
    messageSender.setMessageFormat(MessageFormat.RFC_5424);

but result is the same.
dependency for the library is
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
    <artifactId>syslog-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

